# Creating a linked list class and defining methods in python

Tags: python, linked-list

I am creating a LinkedList class, and I want to define a remove method which will remove a node from the tail.

So far I have:

```
class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def print_things(self):
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            print(current.get_data())
            current = current.get_next()

    def add(self, item): 
        temp = Node(item)
        temp.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = temp    

    def remove(self):
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        found = False
        while not found:
            if current.get_data() != current:
                found = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.get_next()

        if previous == None:
            self.head = current.get_next()
        else:
            previous.set_next(current.get_next())
        return previous
```

Using this, I am trying to run the following code:

```
letter_list = LinkedList()

my_list.add('d')
letter_list.add('c')
letter_list.add('b')
letter_list.add('a')

print(letter_list.remove())
print(letter_list.remove())
print(letter_list.remove())

print('l')
letter_list.print_things()
```

Which gives the output:

```
None
None
None
l
d
```

Even though i was expecting:

```
d
c
b
l
a
```

And this is the node class used:

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, init_data):
    self.data = init_data
    self.next = None

def get_data(self):
    return self.data

def get_next(self):
    return self.next

def set_data(self, new_data):
    self.data = new_data

def set_next(self, new_next):
    self.next = new_next
```

I can't see what I've done wrong in my remove method, but based on the output it seems I'm returning the wrong variable.

Comment: What is `if current.get_data() != current:` supposed to do? Under what circumstances will the result of `get_data()` on a node equal the node, and when will it not be equal? Showing your `Node` class will help get an answer, since the code above depends on its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that this check is always true:

```
if current.get_data() != current:
```

The `data` field of your `Node` objects is never equal to the node objects themselves, so you never examine more than the head of the list. Your `while` loop runs once, sets `found` to `True`, and leaves `previous` set to `None`.

The correct way to do this would be:

```
def remove(self):
    current = self.head
    previous = None
    while current.next is not None:
        previous = current
        current = current.next
    if previous is None:
        self.head = current.next
    else:
        previous.next = current.next
    return previous
```

Some modifications beyond fixing the way you detect reaching the end of the list:

1) I'm not using your getters and setters. Idiomatic Python does not use getters or setters. Instead, you simply define the desired attributes and access them normally. If you need to refactor later to add special behavior when setting or getting them, you use the `property` decorator to change the setting or getting implementation.

2) Comparisons to `None` should be made with `is` or `is not`. This is one of the rare instances in Python where looking for object identity is correct - `None` is a singleton object, so `None` always refers to the same instance. Equality comparisons are potentially vulnerable to buggy implementations.

I mention these things because the only reason to write your own list class in Python is for learning purposes, so you might as well learn the language's idioms in the process.

The above is vulnerable to cyclical lists, such as you'd get by setting the tail's `next` to a node that's already in the list. There are various things you could do to prevent that, such as setting an attribute on nodes to see if they've been inspected already. For a learning exercise, it's probably sufficient to just make sure you don't create such lists.

Comment: This is an excellent explanation! However I am still getting some funny results. I'll work with this and see how I go :)